# woocommerce thumbnails have different image widths in chrome and mozilla

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome, mozilla

Hello I recently run into a weird issue.
I am running a Woocommerce theme built on bootstrap 3.
I did some custom CSS modification and Image thumbnails appear REALLY narrow on Chrome and fine on Thunderbird. Could someone help me? I might be missing something fundamental here...
Before you ask, no I am not running any extensions
Here are the images:

CHROME: http://i60.tinypic.com/37l3b.jpg

MOZILLA: http://i57.tinypic.com/dmpjbn.jpg

**CSS**

```
.thumbcustom{
float:left;
display: -webkit-inline-flex;
display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
display: inline-flex;
max-width:24% !important;
margin-left:7px;
}
```

And the HTML file:

```
                    <?php
            /**
             * Single Product Thumbnails
             *
             * @author      WooThemes
             * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
             * @version     2.3.0
             */

            if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
                exit; // Exit if accessed directly
            }

            global $post, $product, $woocommerce;

            $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

            if ( $attachment_ids ) {
                $loop       = 0;
                $columns    = apply_filters(  'woocommerce_product_thumbnails_columns', 3 );
                ?>
                <div class="thumbnails thumbcustom"><?php

                    foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {

                        $classes = array( 'zoom' );

                        if ( $loop == 0 || $loop % $columns == 0 )
                            $classes[] = 'first';

                        if ( ( $loop + 1 ) % $columns == 0 )
                            $classes[] = 'last';

                        $image_link = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );

                        if ( ! $image_link )
                            continue;

                        $image       = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, apply_filters( 'single_product_small_thumbnail_size', 'shop_thumbnail' ) );
                        $image_class = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $classes ) );
                        $image_title = esc_attr( get_the_title( $attachment_id ) );

                        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="%s" title="%s" data-rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]">%s</a>', $image_link, $image_class, $image_title, $image ), $attachment_id, $post->ID, $image_class );

                        $loop++;
                    } ?>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
```

Comment: That's just the PHP.... what does it render in HTML...

Comment: I will send you a link so you can inspect element. :)

Comment: http://goo.gl/IGdah3 You can inspect the page /element here by right clicking. Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having to override default styles is one of the reasons I hate Bootstrap...

image HTML has a width/height 180px180px... but there is a conflict between parent container for image

**woocommerce-layout.css**

```
#single-product div.thumbnails a {
    width: 100%;
}

.woocommerce #content div.product div.thumbnails a, .woocommerce div.product div.thumbnails a, .woocommerce-page #content div.product div.thumbnails a, .woocommerce-page div.product div.thumbnails a {
   width: 30.75%; 
}
```

set this to be this will fix issue you have in FF as well...

```
#single-product div.thumbnails a {
    width: calc(25% - 2px); //2px compensate for border Doesn't support IE8
}
```

then image has a `max-width 100%` but this is 100% of the container in chrome this translates to about 87px for the image.

Then you have a fixed height set at 112px which makes it out of proportion
**template.css**

```
#single-product div.thumbnails a .attachment-shop_thumbnail {
    height: 112px;
}
```

set it to `height:auto`

Comment: Worked like a charm bro!
Although i couldnt find the elements you mention (#single-product div.thumbnails a for example) i just copied and pasted the code you provide into woocommerce-layout.css.

i also put !importan at the end of each line so it would override any conflicts.

Thanks a lot again!

Comment: You should avoid !important check in the non minified version of CSS and inspect it it in chrome dev tools you should see it... imagine you inherting someone else's important CSS... you will have to start using important to override theirs... that's after you spend few hours trying to figure why your CSS don't work... then suddenly you will have viscous cycle of !important everywhere

Comment: Yes i am aware of the !important issue. Revised the css now ;)
Thanks a lot again for your precious info!